# Add close button in ctools model dialog

Tags: entities, chaos-tool-suite

I am using ctools modal dialog/popup window to display some records. The default close button is working fine. How can I add a custom close button?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by custom close button?  When you say the default button is working fine, it sounds like you don't have any problems.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need this extra button for better user interface.

Answer (score 6):

As for [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1347578) commited on November '11, you should be able to close any CTools modal window with a link that has the class "ctools-close-modal"

For example, in my modal I've got this for element to cancel and close:

```
  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Cancel'), '#',
       array(
         'attributes' => array(
           'class' => 'ctools-close-modal'
          ),
         'external' => TRUE
       )
     )
  );
```

Comment: Actually, your answer is the same as [mine](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30145/add-close-button-in-ctools-model-dialog/#30153).

Comment: yup, but yours is not translation safe, and I like to use more l than raw html

Comment: FYI: I edited the answer, There is no need to have inline javascript in the link tag, that is very bad practice, Also the fragment property isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

Just add CSS class `ctools-close-modal` to any element inside the dialog like this:

```
$form['close_link']['#markup'] = '<span class="ctools-close-modal"> × </span>
<a href="#" class="ctools-close-modal">or click here.</span>';
```

Comment: Thanks Kakabro for your help. I tried the code as `$form['actions']['cancel_button2'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<span class="ctools-close-modal"> × </span><a href="#" class="ctools-close-modal">or click here.</span>', 
  );` but its not working. I have opened the view developed page in ctools model. I tried this `// add a close popup button
 $form['actions']['cancel_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Save'),
    '#submit'   => array('close_model_dialog'),
  );' and submit

Comment: `// function to close the model dialog
function close_model_dialog($form, &$form_state) { 
 ctools_include('ajax');
 ctools_include('modal');
 $form_state['redirect'] = TRUE;
 $form_state['redirect'] = "fee/add"; 
 $output = array();
 $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
 print ajax_render($output);
 exit;
}` but its not working as showing error in case of paging in view.

Comment: "but its not working." — it works and I'm kaLabro :)

Comment: Umar the information you placed in these comments should be a part of your question.  Potential answerers may not read comments under an answer, but they will if its in the question.  You can edit your question to improve it at any time., maybe under a heading such as "Additional Information" to distinguish what you have added.

Comment: Umar, this is what I did after trying both these solutions:

    $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#button_type' => 'cancel',
      '#value' => t('Cancel'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-close-modal')),
    );

or if your Cancel button already exists,

    $form['actions']['cancel']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'ctools-close-modal';